# Alignment in mailto-bodies

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prepopulate the body of a javascript-set mailto-link with structured data I compose of results from multiple API-calls.

What I could not achieve is a proper alignment of the body inside mail-clients.

With Thunderbird 60.2.1 *multiple* %20 are reduced to *single* %20, thus breaking the alignment.

Gmail kept multiple spaces on some places (but not always the original amount) and on some reduced the number of spaces to 1.

I would be thankful for advice on how to achieve an alignment corresponding to the original data.

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` instead

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply; this unfortunately leads to cutting off all text beginning with the first &nbsp; (at least in Gmail).